# Get content of XML node using c#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

simple question but I've been dinking around with it for an hour and it's really starting to frustrate me.  I have XML that looks like this:

```
  <TimelineInfo>
    <PreTrialEd>Not Started</PreTrialEd>
    <Ambassador>Problem</Ambassador>
    <PsychEval>Completed</PsychEval>
  </TimelineInfo>
```

And all I want to do is use C# to get the string stored between `<Ambassador>` and `</Ambassador>`.

So far I have:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\test.xml");
XmlNode x = doc.SelectSingleNode("/TimelineInfo/Ambassador");
```

which selects the note just fine, now how in the world do I get the content in there?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

May I suggest having a look at LINQ-to-XML ([System.Xml.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx))?

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\test.xml");

string result = (string)doc.Root.Element("Ambassador");
```

LINQ-to-XML is much more friendly than the Xml* classes ([System.Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.aspx)).

---

Otherwise you should be able to get the value of the element by retrieving the [InnerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.innertext.aspx) property.

```
string result = x.InnerText;
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to cast to XmlElement - InnerText is defined in the parent XmlNode as virtual and XmlElement just overrides it like normal.

Comment: BTW, in case others run across this - the cast to string is important (XElement defines lots of explicit conversions so you can do stuff like this and not have to call Convert methods yourself) - you might be tempted to ToString instead, but that doesn't get you the same result (it would get the entire element, including opening, closing, and content)

Comment: BTW, since in this example snippet we're not really using the XDocument, a slightly simpler version would be XElement.Load the file which gets you the root element directly.  However, that's just a point of trivia - XDocument.Load is certainly what you want to use in the typical case. :)

Answer (score 4):

The InnerText property should work fine for you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.innertext.aspx

FWIW, you might consider switching API to linq-to-xml (XElement and friends) as IMHO it's a friendly, easier API to interact with.

System.Xml version (NOTE: no casting to XmlElement needed)

```
var xml = @"<TimelineInfo>
                <PreTrialEd>Not Started</PreTrialEd>
                <Ambassador>Problem</Ambassador>
                <PsychEval>Completed</PsychEval>
            </TimelineInfo>";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/TimelineInfo/Ambassador");
Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
```

linq-to-xml version:

```
var xml = @"<TimelineInfo>
                <PreTrialEd>Not Started</PreTrialEd>
                <Ambassador>Problem</Ambassador>
                <PsychEval>Completed</PsychEval>
            </TimelineInfo>";
var root = XElement.Parse(xml);
string ambassador = (string)root.Element("Ambassador");
Console.WriteLine(ambassador);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\test.xml");
XmlNode x = doc.SelectSingleNode("/TimelineInfo/Ambassador");
```

`x.InnerText` will return the contents

Comment: Simple and efficient. Kudos

Answer (score 0):

Try using Linq to XML - it provides a very easy way to query xml datasources - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098%28v=VS.100%29.aspx